# Is this the correct way to write a constructor that extends this other PHP file?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2, extend, construct

I am using Magento 2.2.6. The file I am extending is \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage. It has the following constructor:

```
/**
 * DB Storage table name
 */
const TABLE_NAME = 'url_rewrite';

/**
 * Code of "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" error
 */
const ERROR_CODE_DUPLICATE_ENTRY = 1062;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
 */
protected $connection;

/**
 * @var Resource
 */
protected $resource;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
private $logger;

/**
 * @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
 * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface|null $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    LoggerInterface $logger = null
) {
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource;
    $this->logger = $logger ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);

    parent::__construct($urlRewriteFactory, $dataObjectHelper);
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
private $logger;

/**
 * @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
 * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface|null $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    LoggerInterface $logger = null
) {
    $this->logger = $logger ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);

    parent::__construct($urlRewriteFactory, $dataObjectHelper, $resource);
}
```

Do I want to change:

```
parent::__construct($urlRewriteFactory, $dataObjectHelper, $resource);
```

to

```
parent::__construct($urlRewriteFactory, $dataObjectHelper, $resource, $logger);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending a class and overriding the `__construct()` function you have to pass the parameters that parent requires. So  `\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage::__construct` has folowing params

```
public function __construct(
    UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    LoggerInterface $logger = null
)
```

So the answer is that you need call parent like this `parent::__construct($urlRewriteFactory, $dataObjectHelper, $resource, $logger);`